# How can I determine if instance of class from Django model is subclass of another model?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models, subclass

I have a class called `BankAccount` as base class. I also have `CheckingAccount` and `SavingsAccount` classes that inherit from `BankAccount`.

BankAccount is not an abstract class but I do not create an object from it, only the inheriting classes.

Then, I execute a query like this:

```
account = BankAccount.objects.get(id=10)
```

How do I know if account is `CheckingAccount` or `SavingsAccount`?

The way I do this now is in this way:

```
checking_account = CheckingAccount.objects.get(id=account.id)
```

If it exists, it is a `CheckingAccount`, otherwise, it is a `SavingsAccount`.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Check my approach! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411232/django-multi-table-inheritance-how-to-know-which-is-the-child-class-of-a-model

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to use the `checkingaccount` and `savingsaccount` attributes. The one it is will not blow up.

Comment: What if the attribute name is only known at runtime?

Comment: At runtime, assume you have selected a base `BankAccount` object named `account` and the variable attribute name is `attr_name`. Run `hasattr(account, attr_name)` and you will get True if there is a subclass of that type, or False if it doesn't.

Comment: v1.9 link describing this multi-table inheritance: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance

Answer (score 11):

You could use `isinstance(account, SavingsAccount)`, but is [generally preferred to avoid it](http://www.canonical.org/~kragen/isinstance/) and use [duck type inference](http://www.objectcommando.com/blog/?p=55) by looking at the object's attributes, and see if it quacks like a subclass.

To see if an [object has an attribute](http://www.siafoo.net/article/52#checking-for-property-and-method-existence), you use the aptly named [`hasattr` built-in](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hasattr) [function](http://pyref.infogami.com/hasattr) or use `getattr` and check for the raising of an AttributeError exception.

Comment: the duck type inference link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Add a GetAccountType() method to your Checking and Savings accounts, when you get the object back from BankAccount.objects.get() then call that, if everything that derives from BankAccount has that method then you'll be fine.

Comment: `BankAccount.objects.get()` returns a `BankAccount` object. Always.

Comment: You're right, I thought I was using something similar in my own code but I checked and i'm only ever doing queries based on the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching I found solutions akin to this:
[Django multi-table inheritance, how to know which is the child class of a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411232/django-multi-table-inheritance-how-to-know-which-is-the-child-class-of-a-model)

Basically, there's no elegant solution for this. You have to do a bunch of try-except statements and force django to use the class you want.