# Retrieving a child model's annotation via a query to the parent in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a concrete base model, from which other models inherit (all models in this question have been trimmed for brevity):

```
class Order(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey('OrderState')
```

Here are a few examples of the "child" models:

```
class BorrowOrder(Order):
    parts = models.ManyToManyField('Part', through='BorrowOrderPart')

class ReturnOrder(Order):
    parts = models.ManyToManyField('Part', through='ReturnOrderPart')
```

As you can see from these examples, each child model has a many-to-many relationship of **Parts** through a custom table. Those custom through-tables look something like this:

```
class BorrowOrderPart(models.Model):
    borrow_order = models.ForeignKey('BorrowOrder', related_name='borrowed_parts')
    part = models.ForeignKey('Part')
    qty_borrowed = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class ReturnOrderPart(models.Model):
    return_order = models.ForeignKey('ReturnOrder', related_name='returned_parts')
    part = models.ForeignKey('Part')
    qty_returned = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Note that the "quantity" field in each through table has a custom name (unfortunately): *qty_borrowed* or *qty_returned*. I'd like to be able to query the base table (so that I'm searching across all order types), and include an annotated field for each that sums these quantity fields:

```
# Not sure what I specify in the Sum() call here, given that the fields
# I'm interested in are different depending on the child's type.
qs = models.Order.objects.annotate(total_qty=Sum(???))

# For a single model, I would do something like:
qs = models.BorrowOrder.objects.annotate(
       total_qty=Sum('borrowed_parts__qty_borrowed'))
```

So I guess I have two related questions:

1. Can I annotate a child-model's data through a query on the parent model?
2. If so, can I conditionally specify the field to be annotated, given that the actual field name changes depending on the model in question?

This feels to me like a place where using `When()` and `Case()` might be helpful, but I'm not sure how I'd build the necessary logic.

Comment: Why is the `parts` field not in the parent model? The "through" tables have more differences between them other than different names for the order and quantity fields?

Comment: Yes, the through tables have a number of differences not shown. In retrospect, the "parts" field likely *could* have been in the parent model, but there are a few child models that have unique circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, when you are querying the base model (in multi-table inheritance), it's hard to find out which subclass the object actually is. See [How to know which is the child class of a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411232/django-multi-table-inheritance-how-to-know-which-is-the-child-class-of-a-model).

The query might be achievable in theory, with something like

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN child1.base_ptr_id IS NOT NULL THEN ...
        WHEN child2.base_ptr_id IS NOT NULL THEN ...
    END AS ...
FROM base
    LEFT JOIN child1 ON child1.base_ptr_id = base.id
    LEFT JOIN child2 ON child2.base_ptr_id = base.id
    ...
```

but I don't know how to translate that in Django and I think it would be too much trouble to do it. It could be done, if not anything else using `raw` queries.

Another solution would be to add to the base class a field that specifies which actual subclass each object is; in that case, you'd need to make as many queries as there are subclasses and join them. I don't like this solution either. **Update:** After I slept on this I conclude that the most Django-like solution would be not to query the parent model in the first place; simply query the submodels and join the results. I would explore the third option below only if there were performance or other practical problems.

Another idea is to create a database view (with `CREATE VIEW`) based on the above SQL query and translate it into a Django model with `managed = False`, and query that one. Maybe this is somewhat cleaner than the other solutions, but it is a bit non-standard.

Comment: I do have some machinery to figure out what type of base class each element is, and it's along the route of your second suggestion.

Comment: I added an update in my second suggestion.