# Django filter queryset by attribute subclass

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-inheritance

I have a `Slug` model to identify `Page` objects. A `BlogPost` inherits from `Page`. I want to find a `BlogPost` given a `Slug` name, but no other `Page` objects.

EDIT: added models

```
class Slug(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    page = models.ForeignKey('Page', null=True)

class Page(models.Model):
    slug = models.OneToOneField('Slug', related_name='primary_slug_set')
    content = models.TextField()

class BlogPost(Page):
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
```

I think I'm after something like this:

```
Slug.objects.get(name=slug_name).filter(page=subclass_of(BlogPost))
```

I'm aware of the [InheritanceManager](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) and `select_subclasses(BlogPost)` but my query is for `Slug`, so I can't see that this helps unless I query `Page` and look for a `BlogPost` with my slug (is this a better way?).

Instead of filter I could iterate through all the slug results and manually check each one. It seems [the way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315047/how-can-i-determine-if-instance-of-class-from-django-model-is-subclass-of-anothe) is by checking if the `Slug`'s page has any `BlogPost` attributes. At most there will be only a few slug conflicts to sift through and very rarely any at all.

Is there a way I can get the database query to do the filter for me?

Comment: Could you please post your models?

Comment: @Wtower done, though simplified. I've chosen to allow multiple slugs for each page so if they get edited the old URLs still work.

Answer (score 0):

If your Slug model defines the association with Pages in the following way:

```
class Slug(models.Model):
...
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    page = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Then, your query should look something like this:

```
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(BlogPost)
Slug.objects.filter(name=slug_name, content_type__pk=content_type.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this but give it a try:

```
Slug.objects.filter(name=slug_name, blogpost__isnull=False)
```